# Why Struts giving weird results even outputting the simplest of jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

Trying to get into struts. 
I wrote a normal index.jsp and also did all the struts.xml and web.xml filter mappings. Made a simple action class too with the execute() function returning a result.
But after I convert it to a war file the weirdest of things happens, the source of index.jsp changes. I'm a newbie, i have not seen something like this before.. I mean source code changing itself to something else. 
This is my index.jsp parallel to WEB-INF folder after i create the myapp.war file:

```
PK  ;-G               META-INF/þÊ   PK           PK  ;-G  INF/MANIFEST.MFóMÌËLK-.Ñ
K-*ÎÌÏ³R0Ô3àår.JM,IMÑuª ˜ëÄ›[*hø%&ç¤*8çä%– •kòrñr PK·Œq‰C   D   PK  †-G                Product.javamA‚0E÷&ÞaÂJ7^€x 7†ÄÔiÅ*PÒN‰‰ñî-JÅ’@Âïüÿþ´xµëÕøöþÜhl„sPY#=<€§AË2•NduWC'Zõ£_#ø'=†  µ¢ƒÜlc4ðcyÛ}’_Éø`´æ#;qÑU»ïsÆ©£ŽÜ,ûÎá‚'ÙlI5æf3ââ ®ÆÝ3äùNrèèJnoÉ"Ã1ÿ»«‡BOÜ`Y pQ9WÌnþ¼PK=¿krÎ     PK  q
-G               s1.warðffaààà`(äÕug@œ,¾®!Žºž~núÿN1003x³s€¤˜ Jpjb¸f_G?
```

I believe this is some kind of shorthand and also why the source changes .. also when i go localhost:8080/myapp , this shows up:

```
PKf -G  META-INF/þÊPKPKf -GMETA-INF/MANIFEST.MFóMÌËLK-.Ñ K-*ÎÌÏ³R0Ô3àår.JM,IMÑuª    ˜ëÄ›[*hø%&ç¤*8çä%–•kòrñrPK·Œq‰CDPK†-GProduct.javamA‚0E÷&ÞaÂJ7^€x7†ÄÔiÅ*PÒN‰‰ñî-JÅ’@Âïüÿþ´xµ4íî&A½Ñ•ëÕøöþÜhl„sPY#=<Ã‰Õ<­€§AË2•NduWC'Zõ£_#ø'=†    µ¢ƒÜlc4ðcyÛ}’_Éø`´æ#;qÑU»ïsÆ©£ŽÜ,ûÎá‚
```

Looks pretty same . My real index.jsp is:

```
<html>
  <title>jsp</title>
   <body>
     Success!
   </body>
</html>
```

Also i tried creating index.jsp with struts-tags. Same result.
Not to mention i have included all the Struts jars in the lib folder too.

Comment: It's impossible to help with the information provided. Right now it looks like  that's your war file content. We don't know what you're doing to get these results.

Answer (score 0):

> Every JSP page will be converted into .java & .class file finally by
>   the server using a JDK provided.

**The problem with your JSP file is surely during this conversion process. So check your development environment & server JDK version. Also check if there are any warnings during server start up related to this.**

Comment: Yeah i know that. The thing is it should all happen in the war file i created but no, the source file is getting all the heat? If in any case a person needs to change the source code how can he change it between those scrambled words.